# Looking for a specific LaTeX font

Tags: fonts

Could someone kindly tell me if the following picture illustrate a LaTeX font? If yes, what font is it? It looks like the characters are more dense and thicker (which is what I want) compared to a normal LaTeX font. Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: It looks like the default LaTeX font, yes. But it's not zoomed in enough to be sure.

Comment: I'd say New Century Schoolbook: `\usepackage{newcent}` and, if you need math, `\usepackage{fouriernc}`.

Comment: For me, no it's not Computer Modern. Look at the curl at the beginning of italic m or n or y. Don't you have a .pdf  version? You might know looking at ‘Properties’.

Comment: @Bernard It looked very similar to CM at the first picture. Now it's clearly NC Schoolbook.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The font is NC Schoolbook:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fouriernc}

\begin{document}

\textbf{Pasipoularides.}
\textit{Am J Physiol}
$n=7$
2002.---Functional imaging

\end{document}
```